# rest api - can two endpoints return different models if both return order?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

Is it under the rules of REST to return a different model of 'order' if someone call:

```
/me/orders/222

Return values:
- OrderId
- Price
```

or

```
/customers/111/orders/222

Return values:
- OrderId
- Price
- Tags
- Risk
- Comment
```

Maybe the model of 'order' should always be the same instead of different endpoints? Or it can differ? Is there any rule?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258669/rest-api-can-two-endpoints-return-different-models-if-both-return-order "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: But I didn't get any answer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "rules of REST", but having two different objects with the same name is confusing. And that's basically what you have done here.

I would suggest using the same fields if they are the same thing, or choosing a different name, Item vs Order or whatnot